# Randomized harmonic series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

m is Lebesgue measure on the unit interval and $R_n$ is Radamacher function .
we have this $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (\frac 1i)R_i$ .Show that $S_n$ is converges in $L^2$ .

I have proved Radamacher functions are orthonormal and complete . Now i look for a function in $L^2$ with $\{\frac 1i\} _{i=1}^\infty$ as Fourier coefficients.
Is it true or false? Is there any function with this property?If not , can you suggest me a proof?

Answer (score 1):

By summation by parts,
$\sum_{k=1}^n f_kg_k
=f_1\sum_{k=1}^n g_k+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(f_{j+1}-f_j)\sum_{k=j+1}^ng_k
$,
if $f_k = \frac1{k}$
and $g_k = R_k$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}R_k
&=\sum_{k=1}^n R_k+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(\frac1{j+1}-\frac1{j})\sum_{k=j+1}^nR_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n R_k-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac1{j(j+1)}\sum_{k=j+1}^nR_k\\
\end{array}
$

Here is where I need
properties of the
Radamacher function
that I don't know.

If it behaves
"randomly",
then I would expect that
$|\sum_{j=u}^v R_j|
\le c
$
when
$v-u$
is reasonably large.
for some positive $c$.

If this holds,
then
we might be able to show
that both sums on the right
converge in the sense wanted.

As should be obvious,
I am ventering into
a part of math
that I don't know much about.
It's just a feeling I have
that summation by parts might be useful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I thought.